# What are the differences between difficulty levels in Rage?

Tags: rage

Rage has four difficulty levels:

- Easy
- Normal
- Hard
- Nightmare

What are the differences between them? Do they only affect enemy strength or do they also come into play in racing targets, number of enemies, etc.?

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if there's much of any difference. Playing on Hard right now and even the fights seem pretty tame.

Comment: The AI seems stupid as hell, so I can imagine that if you avoid getting hit too much there shouldn't be too much difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Rage wikia describes:](http://rage.wikia.com/wiki/Difficulty_Levels)

> The enemies appear to have roughly the same amount of health on each
>   level, but hit a lot harder and come in greater numbers as you
>   increase the difficulty. Notable exceptions include the Large Mutants
>   and Krakens, which seem to have lots more health, and the Authority
>   Elite, which are basically tanks on Nightmare, requiring 3 or 4
>   Dynamite Bolt headshots.
>
> Cars in the wasteland will also fight a lot more aggressively and use
>   shields more frequently as you increase the difficulty.
>
> Loot appears unaffected, apart from a Rocket Launcher in Kvasir's Sewer on Hard and Nightmare difficulty.

Comment: I'll just point out that I found that Rocket Launcher in Kvasir's sewer, and I'm playing on normal.